# Find and Replace Function with an Indexed Table

Tags: notepad++

I've been looking around for a while now but I can't find any way to do the exact thing I'm trying to do.

In my project I'm deprecating a function called `DiffVar`, it'd take two arguments in all cases and for all intensive purposes they are always numbers.

I'm in the process of replacing it with inline tables and I can't find a good way to replace all instances of it with those.

Basically this:

```
DiffVar(25, 40)
```

Would have to become this:

```
({25, 40})[Mod.Settings.Difficulty]
```

I'd like to do this with Notepad++'s find and replace features. I've already spent a good amount of time looking into Regex in an attempt to find and replace all instances of `DiffVar` with the new code but I haven't found anything that works.

It just needs to replace the function and the brackets while keeping the arguments intact, since they become the contents of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
DiffVar\(([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)\)
```

And here's the replace

```
({\1, \2})[Mod.Settings.Difficulty]
```